# Forming Heap Using array

Tags: c++, heap, heapsort

I am trying to form a heap using the following code ,But not sure why its not showing the correct output.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int h[10], n;

void heapbottom()
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--) {
        int k = i;
        int v = h[k];
        bool heap = false;
        while (!heap && 2 * k <= n) {
            cout << "\n i value is :" << i;
            j = 2 * k;
            if (j < n)          //there sre 2 children
            {
                if (h[j] < h[j + 1])
                    j++;
            }
            if (v >= h[j])
                heap = true;
            else {
                h[k] = h[j];
                k = j;
            }

            h[k] = v;
        }                       //end of while

    }
    cout << "\n HEAP GENERATED \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << "\n ELEMENT IS:" << h[i];
}

int main()
{

    cout << "\n Enter the maximum number of array elements \n";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "\n Enter the array to perform heap sort \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> h[i];

    heapbottom();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What *is* the correct output? What do you get instead? And how are we supposed to try this code, since it doesn't even compile?

Comment: This is just the functional part of the code I haven't pasted the whole code lets say if I enter 2 9 7 6 5 8 
correct output 
9 6 8 2 5 7
but I am getting 
2 9 7 6 5 8 
which is same as the input

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/CztMUcsa)
you can see the whole code in the specified link

Comment: This makes me wonder why you didn't post the complete code here. It contains much useful information, for example the name of the function and the code where the input is processed.

Comment: Actually I tried to edit the above code and tried to replace it with full source code but I am not able to save it ,due to some problem which is related to the way in which code has been pasted 
that's why I have pasted it in the pastebin whose link is
link:[FULL CODE](http://pastebin.com/ML48hD6c)
This is the first time I asked a code related problem next time onwards I will make sure this won't happen .sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Ok, I pasted the code and formatted it properly. Now the real part can begin …

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Hopefully now someone can help as 
I am not sure why I am getting the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

If I change the outer loop to be

```
for (i = n / 2; i >= 0; i--)
```

I get `9 8 7 6 5 2` as a result, which I believe is a valid heap.